# How to start Vimdiff without equal sections folded?

Tags: folding, vimdiff

I'd like `vimdiff` to start with *all* the folded sections opened.

So far I have tried the following:

```
vimdiff -c "set nofoldenable" -R <(tree -d directory1) <(tree -d directory2)
```

with the `-c "set nofoldenable"` being the attempt to achieve what I want. However, that doesn't work, because it only affects the left window, not the right one.

I want to put this into a shell function for convenience, so the length of the actual invocation doesn't matter to me.

I have also tried `-c "bufdo set nofoldenable"` which has the desired effect w.r.t. the folded sections, but leads `vimdiff` to scroll out of sync and no longer highlights the differences either. So doing this kills all the utility `vimdiff` offers.

Currently I start `vimdiff` and then use the `zR` command to open all folded sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zR` sets `foldlevel` to a high value, so try that:

```
vimdiff -c "set foldlevel=9999" -R <(tree -d directory1) <(tree -d directory2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `windo` instead of `bufdo`:

```
vimdiff -c "windo set nofoldenable" -R <(tree -d directory1) <(tree -d directory2)
```

Comment: I usually have ``vimdiff -c 'windo set syntax=off'`` to remove syntax highlighting in my bash alias, too.